# How do I modify the response url of an ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function, which on success redirects to the response returned from the url:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/someLoginUrl',
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain : true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: false
        },
        success: function(response){
            window.location.href = response;
        }
    });
});
```

The response, which is returned by `http://localhost:8080/someLoginUrl` is just a webpage, containing a url:

This is the html of the response page:

```
<html><head></head><body>https://localhost:8080/anotherLogin</body></html>
```

So, once I click my button `button1`, instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/someLoginUrl`, it redirects to `https://localhost:8080/anotherLogin`, which is the desired behavior for me.
However, I want to do a small manipulation on the `response` inside the `success` function - I want to change the protocol from `https` to `http`. How do I do that?

I tried `response = response.replace('https', 'http');` but this did not change anything.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado first arg in replace method is source and second one is target. So your solution will not work.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil it worked, thanks!

Comment: i'm always a bit surprised when I hear about redirect as response from Ajax. You don't need ajax to do what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

**May Be I understand your Question ! You want your success Response data to your Same page where this action took place**

First You have to create a dive with id **`<div id=res_data> </div>`** and place this div where you want to show your response data .

Then Your Final code is

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/someLoginUrl',
  method: 'GET',
  crossDomain : true,
  xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: false
  },
 success: function(response){
    $('#res_data').val(response);
 }
 });
});
```

Tuned me if you not find this helpful .